# KafkaConsumer doesn't return data from topic

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have several topics that I populated from csv files previously. I want to fetch data and print in Jupyter notebook.
As I had troubles (no errors, just endless execution), I decided to create another topic called "numtest" (created manually) and to populate it with python producer:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
value_serializer=lambda x:
dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

print(str(producer.bootstrap_connected()))

for e in range(100):
data = {'number' : e}
producer.send('numtest', value=data)

print('Done')
```

It returns 'True' and 'Done'. However, when I tried to check the topic from console, I got this:
**root@19f9bec85da8:/opt/kafka/bin# kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic numtest  --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --from-beginning

Processed a total of 0 messages**

I guess, it is empty.

Next block of code in Jupyter is following:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('numtest', bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')),auto_offset_reset='earliest')

topics = consumer.topics()
print(topics)

print(consumer.subscription())
data = consumer.poll(max_records = 1)

print(data)
```

It returns {'numtest', 'water_quality', 'water_quality_by_water_body'} and then {'numtest'} as intended.

At the end I get no data. Nothing is printed, no errors.

All of this is set up in docker.

I tried using topics that I manually created and populated from CSV. Also, tried to use KafkaProducer to get simple topic with int number.
My desired result - topics (which are perfectly readed by console consumer, if populated from CSV file) are fetched to Jupyter notebook, so I can work on data. Would be even better, if I knew why my KafkaProducer populadated topic(number from 1 to 100) could be readed from console and fetched as well.

Comment: Verify that the Kafka broker is accessible and running, and check the consumer's configuration, including the `auto_offset_reset` parameter and message deserialization.

Comment: auto_offset_reset is 'earliest' and broker might be accessible as I can use **./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list** in a container

Answer (score 0):

The producer buffers data, and will not send immediately. You need to flush it before printing Done to ensure the buffer is empty

You also need to indent the for loop. Otherwise, you're only sending one event

For the consumer, you should poll as part of a loop, if you want all messages, and you need to set auto offset reset to earliest offset

Comment: I tried adding flush() before pronting 'Done', but when i check topic size with **kafka-log-dirs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic-list numtest** in a container, it is still zero, nothing is sent.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please edit your question to include your container setup